# BackButton on android phone not working on fullscreen image?

Tags: android

friends,

i am using following property to show image on full screen

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

in manifest file

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {

        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT)
        {

             ShowError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(CurrentImageIndex + 1 < mImage_URL.length )
                {
                    CurrentImageIndex  = CurrentImageIndex +1 ;
                    Move();
                }


        }else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT)
        {

             ShowError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(CurrentImageIndex > 0 )
                {
                    CurrentImageIndex  = CurrentImageIndex -1 ;
                    Move();

                }


        }           
        return true;

    }






}
```

when image is display on full screen then backbutton(Hardware button on phone) does not work.

any one guide me what is the solution?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if should work even with fullscreen. need to see your activity code. for testing, you could override the onBackPressed method, Log and call super.onBackPressed(), see if you even get to there when pressing the back button.

Comment: no i am overriding onkeydown even. and its effecting it. got it thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was override onkeydown event and forgot to write backevent. on keydown event directly effect keypad and backbutton functionality in case of overriding.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();


        }

        return true;

    }
```